# SQL - Select records equal to date, or show all if date is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have the below query which is connected to 3 datasources, which allow NULL values and can be used in any combination to query against the database to filter down the results. So far this is working fine, for @Employee and @Project as they are strings, however the @Week_Ending, being a DataTime value i cant work out how to do this. Currently if the @WeekEnding value is null it returns no records, but works fine if a valid date is entered.

```
SELECT Week_Ending, Employee, Project FROM Times WHERE (Project LIKE ISNULL(@Project, '%')) AND (Employee LIKE ISNULL(@Employee, '%')) AND (Week_Ending = CONVERT(datetime, @WeekEnding, 103))
```

I have found solutions for similar issues but they are all using a results from a range of between of two dates, instead of the single date, which is where i am stuck.

I would like to keep all logic in the SQL query rather than use code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [**catch-all query**](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/). For few conditions, I think you can implement this using the `AND-OR` conditions:

```
SELECT 
    Week_Ending, Employee, Project 
FROM Times 
WHERE
    (@Project IS NULL OR Project LIKE @Project)
    AND (@Employee IS NULL OR Employee LIKE @Employee)
    AND (@WeekEnding IS NULL OR Week_Ending = @WeekEnding)
```

Note, I replace `ISNULL()` with `[column] IS NULL` so that your `WHERE` conditions become SARGable.

Comment: Worked perfectly, just had to add back in my "CONVERT(datetime, @WeekEnding, 103)" section but this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below one :

```
SELECT Week_Ending, Employee, Project FROM Times 
WHERE 
(Project LIKE ISNULL(@Project, '%')) 
AND (Employee LIKE ISNULL(@Employee, '%')) 
AND (Week_Ending =  (case when  @WeekEnding is null then Week_Ending else  @WeekEnding   end))
```